# Why is the capacitor considered lossless, even if it can store/give out energy?

Tags: capacitor, ac, capacitance

They say capacitor is lossless because average power is 0.But contradicting this is the fact that the energy stored/disipated by a capacitor is (1/2)CV^2.How and why is this?

Comment: That's not dissipated. Dissipated is not the same as stored. If you put your sugar into a cabinet, did the cabinet make it go away or is it just storing it for you?

Comment: My bank account is lossless, too.

Comment: @NickJohnson My bank account is half wave rectified.

Comment: My bank account IS a capacitor - too many charges

Comment: My bank account IS a capacitor, but its ESR is too big (darned Italian banks!).

Comment: @Andyaka that's called leakage currency.

Answer (score 3):

Dissipation of energy means transforming it to a form less usable and not easily recoverable to the original one (usually heat).

With capacitor, it is obviously not the case - an ideal capacitor maintains constant voltage on its ends until *you* discharge it by connecting external load. It provides you exactly with the amount of energy you have given it, equal to the expression you wrote. Resistor, for example, "consumes" power as well, but when you disconnect it from the source, it has zero voltage across. Here, the energy has been dissipated into heat and you cannot recover it by any means.

Real capacitor, though, has some parallel leakage conductance preventing it to stay charged forever. When using it in an AC circuit, dynamic losses in the dielectric dissipate some power as well, this is quantified by Dissipation factor, \$\tan \> \delta\$.

Answer (score 0):

A capacitor stores the charge Q=CU. Because the voltage over the cap increases linearly in an RC circuit when it's charged, it will finally hold an energy of E=1/2CU^2.

However, the power supply provided the entire charge with its full voltage, so it delivered an energy of E=CU^2.

Whenever you charge a capacitor and the resistance of the system is not zero,  you waste 50% of the primary energy.

Using a cap as energy storage is everything but lossless.

Comment: The capacitor is in this case still lossless, the circuit will dissipate 50% unfortunately...

Comment: Using a cap as energy storage in a switch-mode power supply (where the cap is charged by an inductor) is fairly efficient, even though the resistance of the system is non-zero, the inductor provides a way to charge the cap without incurring the 50% penalty.

Answer (score 0):

An ideal cap is lossless since there is no mechanism by which it can dissipate energy. Any energy put in is stored, and possibly later put out again.

A real physical cap can lose energy by heating up (due to internal resistance) and then radiating the energy away, so it is not lossless.

Answer (score 0):

Average power of a capacitor is zero for perfect symmetrical ac input voltages only, e.g: sine/cos signal. Here, Average power is defined as the net power the capacitor has stored/dissipated over a cycle of the input sinusoidal voltage. An ideal capacitor, in the first half cycle, it stores some energy, P. And it dissipates the **same energy P** in the next half cycle. so the **net energy = P + (-P) = 0** ; hence power = rate of change of energy is also zero. This is the same with inductor too. Thus, ideal C and L don't consume any energy in an ac circuit. So we say they are lossless. The equation E = 0.5 CV^2 is applicable in this case too; but v is a time varying signal, so we have to integrate and find the total power. In fact, if you calculate the power in both cycles separately, you will arrive at the same result, when you add them finally. Considering a DC circuit, if an ideal capacitor is charged with a DC voltage and allowed to discharge at power-off, the average power maybe expressed in sum of stored and dissipated energies, which is equal to 0 too.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. (1) "Dissipated" suggests power given off as heat by the capacitor so it might not be the best word. See @Ladislav's answer. Storing / delivering might be better. (2) "*Average power of a capacitor is zero for a perfect sine/cos signal input voltage ONLY.*" What law is this? (3) Can you explain then what happens, for example, with a triangle wave? (4) Can you explain what happens in a DC example when a capacitor is charged up on power-on and discharged at power-off?

Comment: 3)if it is a perfect triangle wave with equal rising and falling time, then net power would be zero. If it is unequal, it wont be. You can integrate and confirm

Comment: 4) charged up using a DC and then discharged at power off means, you varied the input voltage right? oh ya ideally, it will dissipate the same power as it stored before. I meant, if the input is a constant DC forever, average power is nothing but the stored energy itself, which is not zero in that circuit.

Comment: 2) I meant for perfect/fundamental sinusoidal waves. In fact, for any symmetrical AC wave. I would let go of that "ONLY" then :P

Comment: 1) yea true upto some point.

Comment: (3) OK, I see your "sine only" assertion has been removed. But you are still saying the waveform has to be symmetrical (about zero). It doesn't. e.g., Fast high current charge and long slow discharge. (4) Agreed, but it's another exception to your assertion. (2) It doesn't have to be symmetrical. See (3). I think some more revision might be required. You might reconsider your first sentence in the light of all this.

Comment: yea.....By "Symmetrical" I just meant, same rising and falling time/transitions. I did not think about that "zero" thing.

Answer (score 0):

No real capacitor is loss less but an ideal one is and some real ones almost are.

With an ideal capacitor you can store energy in it by charging it.

$$E = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot C \cdot V^2$$

But you can get that energy back by discharging the capacitor. The energy you put in is equal to the energy you get back. There is no loss of energy.

Similarly, with an ideal inductor you can store energy in it by putting current through it.

$$E = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot L \cdot I^2$$

But you can get that energy back by reducing the current to zero. The energy you put in is equal to the energy you get back. There is no loss of energy.

For a lossy component you get less energy back than you put into it. An ideal resistor for example will take energy in.

$$E = \int V \cdot I \text{d}t$$

But you can't get any of it back so all that energy is lost to heat.

Some components will return some energy but less than you put in

Comment: Of course! I misread. I'll delete my comment and this one after a while.

Answer (score 0):

The energy \$E = \frac{1}{2}CV^2\$ is not dissipated by the capacitor but by the resistance of the wire connecting the battery and the capacitor. The battery transfers a charge of \$Q = CV\$ across its own potential difference V. So the work done by the battery is \$W = CV^2\$. But since the capacitor **stored** only half of this power, we conclude that half of it is dissipated by the **wire resistance** and not the capacitor.